Where to get current http_proxy setting
I have an Ubuntu (22.04) machine, where the proxy is set from GUI.
I have a job running in crontab. How can I access the actual proxy settings from the cron job? In normal shell, there is an env variable $http_proxy, but I cannot find the actual proxy IP under /etc with grep.

Have you also grepped your home directory: cd; grep http_proxy .*? (include hidden files)

@moo Yes, but found only in .bash_history :)
